# Building chm file with chmcmd result in javascript error on all page

Tags: doxygen, chm

My project is documented using doxygen, and I would like to create a chm file under Linux, so I'm using chmcmd.

The chm is built, but on every page I have this error

```
« $ » is undefined
code 0
```

When checking the file, it correspond to this function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  initMenu('',false,false,'search.php','Search');
});
</script>
```

But if Im building the chm using the windows tool, the file is exactly the same and I dont have the javascript error.

Is there an option to build chm file or something that can change the javscript behaviour?

Comment: Do you open the file on Linux or windows, do you unblock the file after transfering from linux to windows?  (google  for " chm unblock" )

Comment: Forgot to update this post, but it was actually a bug from chmcmd, it is now fixed in the trunk version

Comment: Ah that, yeah I fixed that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by a bug in chmcmd that did not parse .js files. So the javascript files were missing from the chm.

Bug is now fixed in the trunk version.

Latest trunk build can be found here : ftp://ftp.freepascal.org/pub/fpc/snapshot/trunk/

You can also build from source if you want, more info available in their wiki : http://wiki.freepascal.org

Comment: Can you add a link to the trunk version of chmcmd so others can find it easy as well

Comment: Link to latest build added